# Differentiate user signup versus login for AWS Cognito callback

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm using Cognito and have a successful flow to my backend service (a lambda function).

I would like to only create a user on signup, not login. However, Cognito calls back to the same URL for login.

Currently, I'm taking the `code` in the query param and exchanging it for `id_token`, `access_token`, and `refresh_token`. In the `id_token`, there's an email, which I use to query DynamboDB.

I would like to save a call the call to DynamoDB so I'm wondering if there was a way to differentiate signup versus login in either the headers or the tokens?